# pass controller with parameter in ajax symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm work with symfony for an E-commerce project. I have like to display a pop-up window in relation to each product. this pop-up window have a list choices. so for that I like to pass the controller for this window by Ajax to be dynamic , for that :

**Code HTML**

```
  {% for  p in products %}
     <a id="#basket-modal" href="#" data-id="{{ p.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{ modal }}" class="btn btn-primary">
  {% endfor %}
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#basket-modal").on({ click: function() {


   var op_prod_id = $(this).data('id');

   $.ajax({

       url: "{{ path('ajout_prod_panier', {'id': op_prod_id }) }}" , 
       type: "POST",
       data: "op_prod_id="+op_prod_id,
       success: function(data, status, xhr) {
         console.log(data); 
       },
   error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {
     console.log(error);
       }
   });
   event.stopPropagation();
 }
});
});
</script>
```

the problem that always I have an error message :

> Variable "op_prod_id" does not exist.

in url:

> "{{ path('ajout_prod_panier', {'id': op_prod_id }) }}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var op_prod_id = $(this).data('id');` is a js variable.

`{{ path('ajout_prod_panier', {'id': op_prod_id }) }}` is a twig expression.

Try something like that:

```
 <a href="#" data-id="{{ p.id }}" data-url={{ path('ajout_prod_panier', {'id': p.id}) }}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{ modal }}" class="basket-modal btn btn-primary">
```

and in your js

```
$(".basket-modal").on({ click: function() {

    var op_prod_id = $(this).data('id');
    var op_prod_url = $(this).data('url');
    ....
    url: op_prod_url
```

Comment: thanks @Doydoy44 it can be solution : but I have an other error in "$(document).ready(function()" => $ is not defined

Comment: @DhiaEddineFarah: This error means that your jquery file is not load before your js code.

Comment: I added "  <script src="{{ asset ('template/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') }}"></script> " before the script, this error does not display, but the pop-up window does not display

Comment: @DhiaEddineFarah: I guess it's the same type of error, so try do put your js code after all js plugins, and use your js console log to debug. Good luck. :)

Comment: I do all that you tell me , but  the pop-up still does not display :/

Comment: Try to change `<a id="#basket-modal" ` to `<a class="basket-modal" ` and `$("#basket-modal").on({ click: function()` to `$(".basket-modal").on({ click: function()`

Comment: I can't change the class , because iI declared it as a button class

Comment: add class `basket-modal` in your exist class like that `class="basket-modal btn btn-primary"`

Comment: I change it but I return to the 1st problem : 'Uncaught ReferenceError: op_prod_id is not defined'

Comment: I update my answer to change `Id` to `class`. If it's not working with this change, try to post a new question, because it's not the same problem and I have not enough information to solve this.

Comment: Yes thanks @doydoyd44 , this problem is solved, and I should ask an other question for the displaying of the modal